# How to make keyboard show up but not cover the element at the bottom of the screen Swift 4?

Tags: ios, keyboard, swift4

I have a layout like below for my screen, it is a `TextView` on top,and 2 button at the bottom :

[image]

What I want is the keyboard appear at the bottom of the 2 button.The desired output will be like this whenever the keyboard is showed up:

[image]

Therefore I implement this code in my `ViewController` :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.statusTextView.perform(
        #selector(becomeFirstResponder),
        with: nil,
        afterDelay: 0.1)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

 }

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

By the code above the keyboard is show under 2 button at the bottom,the `textView` is move up as well.Here is the output:

[image]

As you can see,the `textView` is moved up as well.Therefore it not appear in the screen.
So my question is,how to make the keyboard show without cover any element in the bottom and not affecting the element as well?

After implement the solution from @D.Desai,I get this error in my Xcode

[image]

Comment: set frame for **showing**  `self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,y: self.view.frame.origin.y,width: self.view.frame.width,height: window.origin.y + window.height - keyboardSize.height)`

for **hiding**  `height: viewHeight + keyboardSize.height`

Comment: hey sir,do u mean add the code in `KeyboadWillShown` and `KeyboardWillhide` ?

Comment: @D.Desai sorry I need in Swift..can you show me the example on how to do it??

Comment: yes  @ken we just need to manage height of view when keyboard is show or hide

Comment: did this code worked?

Comment: in this error you need to add **if** before `let window`

Comment: @D.Desai but now have another strange problem,when I hide the keyboard and appear again,the 2 button in the bottom is disappear never come out..you have any idea on this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
        let window = self.view.window?.frame 
        // We're not just minusing the kb height from the view height because
        // the view could already have been resized for the keyboard before
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                 y: self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                 width: self.view.frame.width,
                                 height: window.origin.y + window.height - keyboardSize.height)
    } else {
        debugPrint("We're showing the keyboard and either the keyboard size or window is nil: panic widely.")
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                 y: self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                 width: self.view.frame.width,
                                 height: viewHeight + keyboardSize.height)
    } else {
        debugPrint("We're about to hide the keyboard and the keyboard size is nil. Now is the rapture.")
    }
}
```

Comment: hey sir,thanks for the answer,but the code having this error `Variable used within its own initial value` at the line `height : window.origin.y` I add `self.window.origin.y` I have the compile error

Comment: can u plz share the screenshot also upvote if u find this answer useful

Comment: ok..I already edit my answer to attach the screenshot..Please take a look